# How do I edit code where only one character is wrong?

Tags: discussion

I found some Python code that that has a closing parenthesis, `)`, too much which results in invalid code.

Now Stack Exchange tells me when editing that code:

```
Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve in this post?
```

How do you circumvent this and still help the community?

The posting is:
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19233278/edit

The wrong line in there is:

```
binary = ' '.join(format(ord(letter), 'b') for letter in str))
```

It should be (one closing parenthesis too much):

```
binary = ' '.join(format(ord(letter), 'b') for letter in str)
```

Also I'm sorry about the tag; I couldn't find an appropriate one.

Comment: You couldn't find a more appropriate tag because this question should have been asked on [Meta].

Comment: FWIW, I edited the answer as per your text above. I also capitalised `JSON` and changed `e.g` at the start of a sentence to `For example`, something that would have *easily* pushed you over the six-character minimum :-)

Comment: thank you, someone who will find that code in the future will be gratefull   for not running into that syntax error.